# LARS package in R with specific lambda value

Tags: r, estimation, lasso, sparse, lars

I am trying to use the LARS package in R to obtain a Lasso estimate of the sparse coefficient vector, say $\hat{\beta}_{\text{sparse}}$, as opposed to a coefficient path. In other words, I am not interested in choosing $\lambda_n$ using CV or BIC/AIC. I am more interested in inputing a scaled theoretical $\lambda_n$ of the form, say,

> \begin{equation} \lambda_n=\sqrt{ \frac{2\sigma^2\log(p-k)\log(k)}{n}}
>  \end{equation}

[see [*Sharp Thresholds for High-Dimensional and Noisy Sparsity Recovery Using $\mathscr{l}_1$-Constrained Quadratic
Programming (Lasso)* by Martin Wainwright](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewainwrig/Papers/Wai09_Sharp_Journal.pdf), if you want a description of the parameters].

While this is possible using the package 'glmnet', LARS does not seem to provide this option. I wondered if this is at all possible using LARS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605740 the paper you're referring to?

Comment: @ThePointer that is indeed the one.

Comment: So shouldn't it be "*Sharp thresholds for high-dimensional and noisy recovery of sparsity* by Martin Wainwright" rather than "Sharp Thresholds for High-Dimensional and Noisy Sparsity Recovery Using -Constrained Quadratic Programming (LASSO) by Martin Wainwright"? Also, feel free to hyperlink the arxiv link to the paper.

Comment: @ThePointer no sorry, I guess I did not check the link properly. The title is correct. See: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wainwrig/Papers/Wai09_Sharp_Journal.pdf

Comment: Ok, I have improved the reference for you in the edit.

Comment: Also, can you please clarify and explicitly state your question? It isn't totally clear to me what your specific question is.

Comment: @ThePointer that is a good point. On a second read it doesn't sound clear to me either haha. Well the package LARS in R gives you a coefficient path for a range of lambda values. Say I want to get coefficients for a predetermined lambda using the LARS package. Is that possible? For instance using predict.lars and setting argument 's' to that lambda and 'mode=lambda'. Just not sure how to go about it (and I don't want to use glmnet package).